# Is there isDestroyed() for Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Activity has isDestroyed(), but I can't find the counterpart for Fragment.

I could override onDestroyed() to set a flag for myself but I assume there's an existing solution.

I'm trying to check whether a fragment is destroyed or not in a network response before updating UI in the fragment.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this check to see if it's destroyed?

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, I'm trying to check if a fragment is destroyed or not in a network response, to decide whether to update UI components.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can create a Fragment as your parent of other fragments and use following code to check is destroyed functionality.

```
public abstract class ASafeFragment extends Fragment
{
    protected boolean isSafe()
    {
        return !(this.isRemoving() || this.getActivity() == null || this.isDetached() || !this.isAdded() || this.getView() == null);
    }
...
}
```

or

```
public static boolean isSafeFragment( Fragment frag )
{
    return !(frag.isRemoving() || frag.getActivity() == null || frag.isDetached() || !frag.isAdded() || frag.getView() == null );   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since all fragments are destroyed if the activity is destroyed, a simple answer could be calling `getActivity().isDestroyed()` returning true if the activity is destroyed, therefore the fragment is destroyed. Nesting fragments is generally not a good idea.

You could also override the fragments `onDestroyView()` method checking and setting boolean variable to true

Comment: It's not good enough, imagine you have a fragment, executing an async task. 
Then for whatever reason, you change the fragment, within the same activity. 
The async task of the first frag completes, and it's a crash. 

Overall it's always good to unsub / cancel all async stuff when destroying views. But sometimes, it's not easily doable because of the lack of methods (fusedLocationClient.lastLocation, **** you). So we need a fragment related check.

Comment: A fragment can be destroyed while it's activity is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to check if a fragment is destroyed or not in a network
>   response, to decide whether to update UI components.

You can use `onDestroyView()` because UI update is not possible after `onDestroyView()` gets called since UI gets destroyed.
Before doing any UI update , you can check if `getActivity()` is `null` or not.

Answer (score 0):

The most bulletproof pattern to decide how to deal with work that may be in progress is to put that work in a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/Loader.html).  The [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager.html) for the fragment/activity will be smart about invoking your [LoaderCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html) only when it's an appropriate time to handle those results, or possibly even retain the results for a replacement fragment/activity after a configuration change.  It's extra coding, but it's the best way to recover from interruption and cancellation.

Comment: Thanks for introducing Loader. I read the Doc and a tutorial, the concept looks good but it's somewhat cumbersome for my simple task.

Answer (score -1):

From [developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) site: "when the activity is destroyed, all fragments will be destroyed." All fragmetns are contained in an activity so you should check your activity.

There is no isDestroyed() for fragments

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I now know there are alternatives.